# Google app engine: get string from a form

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode

I have the following google app engine system:

model.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

class SignUp(ndb.Model):
    ...
    category  = ndb.StringProperty()
    ...
```

html:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
...
<form ...>
  ...
  <input type=radio name=category value=論文>論文
  ...
```

main.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

...
signUp = SignUP()
...
signUp.category = self.request.get('category')
if signUp.category=='論文':
    ...
```

In the above, the value of the radio input is Chinese characters. When running, I got the error message about the `if` statement:

```
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

What was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell python that you want `'論文'` to be interpreted as a unicode string, e.g.:

```
if signUp.category == u'論文':
```

Note the added `u`.

Now you'll be comparing a unicode string to a unicode string, you won't get that warning, and the strings will evaluate as being equal (when `signUp.category` actually is "論文", of course).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably comparing a str to an unicode object, you have to make sure both of them are unicode.

This is an example of an unicode an a str:

```
In [11]: type("hello".decode('utf-8'))
Out[11]: unicode

In [12]: type("hello")
Out[12]: str
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import hashlib
```

use hashlib like this:

```
signUp.category = self.request.get('category')
if signUp.category==hashlib.sha1('論文'.encode('utf-8')):
```